# Avoid data insert into mysql db when auto refreshing a Div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm inserting the page url into my activity log table whenever user navigates through my website. In one of the pages, I have an auto refresh Div. When the user lands to this page, the page url is inserted into my db table whenever the Div auto refreshes. Can someone help me to avoid this insert. I would like to insert the url data only once on manual navigation.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO activity_log (user_email, url, userIp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $user_email, $curPageName, $ip);
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
```

And here is my auto refresh Div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
      $("#autorefreshdiv").load(window.location.href + " #autorefreshdiv" );
}, 10000);
});
```

Comment: I suppose you add a query string to the URL and then check for it.

Comment: am able to get the url to the table. but the issue is, every time the div refreshes, a new row is inserted into the db table with the same details except for the timeframe.

Comment: Yes I got that. `window.location.href + "&foo=1"`. Check for `$_GET['foo']` in PHP.

Comment: Oops, ignore my last comment, I misread your code.